# Simple Python code for posting to Google+

Tags: python, google-plus

I'd like to post to G+ from my application much like I already do in a few lines of code to Twitter. I've been looking at the sample code at code.google.com, and, while the API looks very powerful, the documentation makes this simple task seem immensely complicated. Can someone provide a pointer to a simple snippet of code that simply posts some text to my own G+ account?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to use an Interactive Post. There is no way to programmatically write a post on behalf of a user, but you can create a Share option for the user with prefilled text and recipients. It renders as a button. There's an example below.

Learn more at: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive

Also, the code.google.com resource is out of date. All updated samples are at https://github.com/googleplus/. Specifically, you are probably interested in the PhotoHunt Server in Python to see all of the features that the Google+ API offers (https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-photohunt-server-python).

For an example of an Interactive Post in the PhotoHunt, check https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-photohunt-server-python/blob/master/static/js/controllers.js#L253.

Comment: Wow, this is already great information. I had even searched GitHub already (my goto for stuff like this) and never came across these resources. I'm curious about what you say that "There is no way to programmatically write a post on behalf of a user". What about if that user is me, and I'm posting it on behalf of myself on my own G+ "wall"?

Answer (score -1):

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/ should fit your needs.

There is an example ( http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/plus/plus.py ) with some google+ actions:

```
import sys

from oauth2client import client
from apiclient import sample_tools


def main(argv):
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'plus', 'v1', __doc__, __file__,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me')

  try:
    person = service.people().get(userId='me').execute()

    print 'Got your ID: %s' % person['displayName']
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. I have already seen and investigated this. The issues I have with Google's sample code is 1) none of it demonstrates the simple task of posting something to your own page, 2) It is completely unclear which credentials would be required for that task and 3) they've 'abstracted' a lot of code into 'sample_tools', which seems only to serve to complicate things further and requires multiple files, etc. to do a tiny task.

Comment: @mkoistinen It's not really that trivial of a task... what they're abstracting is actually a reasonably complex process of posting and authenticating

Comment: Just a heads up, the Python sample you're pointing to is not the most ideal one for Google+. Please see the Python quickstart at: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/python